# Question in number theory related to sin

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have a problem with proving the following question:

Prove that there exists $x_0\in (0,\pi)$ and $s_0>0$ such that $|\sin(kx_0)|\geq s_0 k^{-1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Here is my solution:

First, I showed that for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ irrational number, there exists $c_0>0$ such that $d(\alpha, \frac{m-1}{m})\geq c_0m^{-2}$.
I showed that letting $\alpha$ be any irrational number in $(0,1)$, and then fixing $c_0 \leq \alpha$.Then I used induction on $k$, and I got what I want.

Second, I fixed $x_0$ to be $x_0:=\alpha \pi$ such that $x_0 \in (0,\pi)$, and I conclude by the first step that for any $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, we have that 
$$d(kx_0,k\pi)=d(k(\alpha \pi),k\pi )) \geq c_0(k\pi)k^{-2}=c_0\pi k^{-1}.$$

Third step is to show what I want. I am getting stuck here, I tried induction on $k$ by letting $s_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $|\sin (x_0)|\geq s_0$ but I could not go along with that. Also, I tried proving by a contradiction but does not work with me, as well. So I really appreciate any hint or help with that or any other ways or ideas to prove that.

Thank you.

Comment: what is d()? are you taking derivatives?

Comment: OH NO I mean the distance

Comment: You are seemingly using a hammer to kill a fly. For better feedback on your method, it would be helpful if you define the domain of the new variables and the purpose of the new function. Is that euclidean distance? Your idea to ensure an irrational argument for the sin function(and thus a non-zero functional value) is good. But if you fix $x_0$ before choosing k, it may be impossible to prove the original statement. However, if you let $x_0$ be a function of $k$, as in the hints in my answer, then the proof immediately follows.

Comment: @ David Diaz Yes, I think choosing $x_0$ to be a function of $k$ is better than my choosing for $x_0$ to be $\alpha \pi$ with $0<\alpha<1$ being irrational. But what does $n$ refer to in your defining for $x_0$ that is $x_0=\frac{1}{k}\left(\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: I think you can pick any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ I only included it to highlight that your $x_0$ should be picked to maximize $\sin(kx_0)$

Answer (score 0):

The range of the absolute value of the sin function is [0,1].

Note, $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z^+}$:

$$|\sin(kx_0)|\geq s_0 k^{-1}\rightarrow k\cdot |\sin(kx_0)|\geq s_0$$

So you are left trying to prove that some fraction of $k$ is bigger than some $s_0$ of your choosing.

Hints:
 - pick $s_0 < 1$
 - You can make $k\cdot |\sin(kx_0)| = k$ by choosing $x_0$ correctly. Specifically, you need $kx_0 = \pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: But I fix $x_0$ to be irrational, so what you mean by $kx_0=n\pi+\pi/2?$

Comment: @Ahmed I dont understand your proof well enough to comment on it. One obstacle is your introduction of undefined terms like d() and m. This answer is a suggestion for another direction. Note that $x_0$ is necessarily irrational in the equation you cite, but it is not necessary to prove or even state this, so long as it is understood that $x_0$ is a real number

Comment: I mean by d() the distance function, and by m a positive integer.

Comment: Could you please explain more, because that does not with me. I amchoosing $x_0=\alpha \pi$ such that $\alpha \in (0,1)$ irrational.